# Unable to resize a ViewController's view when added on other ViewController's view

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, viewcontroller

i am adding the view controller's view on other view controller's view(content view) from coding using storyboard, the problem is now is the i have some animation the is applied on content view, in that i am resizing the frame, that is not actually working. my code for this is-

```
UIViewController *tempVC=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TempVC"];
[self addChildViewController:tempVC];

tempVC.view.frame=self.contentView.frame;
[self.contentView addSubview:tempVC.view];
```

and animation code is

```
- (IBAction)xClicked:(id)sender {

CGRect swapperRect=self.swapperView.frame;
swapperRect.origin.y=114;
swapperRect.size.height=340;

CGRect menuFrame=self.menuView.frame;
menuFrame.origin.x=0;

CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -1000.0;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, -M_PI * 0.2, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{

    self.swapperView.frame=swapperRect;

    self.swapperView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
    self.swapperView.layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;

} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    // code to be executed when flip is completed
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        self.menuView.frame=menuFrame;
        self.swapperView.center=CGPointMake(330, 284);
    }];
}];

}
```

[image]

problem can be seen that the right view must be resized, that is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

Turn Off Auto Layout for that view, Or Use AutoLayout adjusting code for framing.

Comment: check your frame in console what you are assigning to it, is it the one you want to assign

Comment: everything is perfectly setting.

Comment: if every thing is working fine, frame is ok after animation? if Yes then double check your view Outlet or variable..

Comment: actually if i add view from coding then this problem arise, but working good when adding from storyboard and adding all autoresizing masks.